# How to use SMART via Zabbix?

Tags: zabbix, smartctl

I've been trying to use SMART tools for a time over zabbix, but I just cannot figure it out, why it's not working.

```
Server: debian 10 4.19.0-17-amd64, zabbix: 6.0.0 Revision 5203d2ea7d
Client: debian 11 5.10.0-0.bpo.12-amd64, zabbix: 6.0.0 Revision 5203d2ea7d
```

I installed agent2 and smartmontools on the client, altered the user settings. In the Zabbix web application on this particular client host I added the `SMART by Zabbix agent 2` template (also updated the template file), and thus I can see its inheritant macros in the settings.

However whatever I do, the only value I get from this host is this:
[image]

It doesn't matter where I look for the values, this empty variable is all I get.

I tried to look it up online, but everyone else seems to get the needed values right away after adding the template. I simply cannot find any else settings in the Zabbix control panel... Does anyone have any idea what am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure that the underlying device support smart reporting/monitoring?

Comment: On that device if I use `smartctl -a /dev/sda1` for example, I can see plenty of (non-zero) metrics, so I suppose it should support it (also at the summary it states smart support is available and enabled).

Comment: Did you check the logs of Zabbix server and agent for error messages? `smartctl` needs root privileges to access the devices. Is the host configured to provide root access to the Zabbix agent?

Comment: Typically you  monitor the device and not partitions on the device, so `/dev/sda` rather than `/dev/sda1` might be needed.

Comment: I set the root privilege for the smartctl. On the server I see these errors about this client device:

`error reason for "debian:smart.disk.get" changed: Failed to execute smartctl: Command execution failed: exit status 1.  `

`error reason for "debian:smart.disk.get" changed: Cannot fetch data: Failed to scan for devices: Cannot unmarshal JSON: invalid character 's' looking for beginning of value..  `

`item "debian:smart.disk.get" became not supported: Cannot fetch data: Failed to scan for devices: Cannot unmarshal JSON: invalid character 's' looking for beginning of value..`

Comment: If I run `sudo -u zabbix sudo smartctl -A /dev/sda` on the device, I get normal SMART output, so I don't think there's privilege problems.